# how to say notification bar not closing after click by notification

Tags: android, notifications

I create notification `onReceive` in `BrodcastReceiver` and after clicking on it call another receiver which show progress download in notification;

I need not closing notification drawer after click. How can I do it?

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v(TAG, "show first notification");


    final Notification.Builder mBuilder;
    final NotificationManager mNotifyManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context);


    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, SecondReceiver.class);
    resultIntent.setAction("second notif");

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    context,
                    0,
                    resultIntent,
                    0
            );

        mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setContentText("Tap")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launch)
                .setAutoCancel(

    mNotifyManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: p.s. on clicking by notification I start download and show progress

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if i am right or not but may be there is issue at your this line:-

```
.setAutoCancel(

    mNotifyManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

- Change it by

`setAutoCancel(false);`

--**Add this line**

```
|= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

---Update Answer---

```
.setOngoing(true)
```

-Add above line to your code and still its not working then tell me and if it is then please vote up my answer thanks!

-Hopefuly this one helps .Thanks!
-Or yes any person can also correct if this way is wrong.!

Comment: my bad, I deleted some text; it was:
                  .setAutoCancel(false) 

it's not working for me(

Comment: use only setongoing method and try it. and if it is still causing an issue then we realy need to find it out.Let me inform if you need further help!

Comment: Hello i have found something try that thing also